# Datatables json issue in output: Cannot set property 'nTf' of undefined

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I have the following code to get JSON data into a Datatable. The Json URL is fine when accessing it directly; the JSON is validated. However nothing loads in to the table.

Is there anything in the JS or are the CDN included in the wrong order? According to several examples this should work. Thanks for your help!

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" type="text/css">
  <title>Table</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table table-hover table-stripe" id="example_table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>User</td>
        <td>Party</td>
        <td>Agent</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>

  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var example_table = $('#example_table').DataTable({
      ajax: {
        url: 'json_user.php', // the url to get data from
        dataSrc: function(data) {
          return data.data; // returning the source of the data (it requires an array of data)
        }
      },
      columns: [{
        data: "USERID" // 1st column will render the "id" from data
      }, {
        data: "PARTYID" // 2nd column will render the "name" from data
      }, {
        data: "Agent" // 3rd column will render the "position" from data
      }]
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My JSON looks like this :

```js
{
  "data": [{
      "PARTYID": "9999",
      "USERID": "oaeg",
      "REG_DATE": "2017-04-11 10:19:24",
      "LAST_DEPOSIT_DATE": null,
      "LAST_DEPOSIT_AMOUNT": null,
      "LAST_WITHDRAW_DATE": null,
      "LAST_WITHDRAW_AMOUNT": null,
      "AgentID": null,
      "Agent": "John"
    }, {
      "PARTYID": "1000001",
      "USERID": "Master",
      "REG_DATE": "2019-03-08 16:03:52",
      "LAST_DEPOSIT_DATE": null,
      "LAST_DEPOSIT_AMOUNT": null,
      "LAST_WITHDRAW_DATE": null,
      "LAST_WITHDRAW_AMOUNT": null,
      "AgentID": null,
      "Agent": null
    },
    // ...
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first error in the console:

> Cannot set property 'nTf' of undefined

Is because you have more `td` elements in the footer than you do in the rest of the table. Once you fix that you get this error:

> TypeError: h.ajax is not a function

This is because you're using the 'slim' branch of jQuery which has lots of functionality removed, primarily to do with animation and AJAX. The latter of which is required for this to work. As such you need to use the full version of jQuery:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Once you've fixed those problems your code should work fine, assuming the JSON is returned as you expect it to be.